# Regex matching whitespace and well as non-white space

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a string.

1. String can contain whitespaces
2. The string should contain atleast one non-white space character.

I tried,

```
[^\s]
```

This is matching all non-white space characters.

Any improvement to the above regex will be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question can be reduced to "anything, as long as there is a single non-whitespace chacacter", then `.*\S.*` should work.

Comment: +1, and this can also be delimited with `^` and `$` to match the whole string you have.

Comment: Confused which one to select as right answer.  Since you have answered first, i am selecting your's as the right answer. davidrac and Babak Naffas answer were also working.

Answer (score 2):

try `.*\S.*`  this should match what you're after

Comment: tripleee's answer is more accurate, as '.' matches whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

`\S` is equivalent to `[^\s]`. Was that your question?

Answer (score 1):

**Update, misread the question.**

Try `.*\w.*` as your expression. This will match any string that contains at least a single non-white space. In defining your regex, make sure to escape the backslash, so use `".*\\w.*"` as your String.